# Pacman Hook: Passing Target to Hook-Script

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

Is it possible to pass the target variable to the hook script?

Need it for kernel-module saving mechanism, when another kernel is updated (linux) instead of my running one (linux-hardened).

```
[Trigger]
Operation = Upgrade
Type = Package
Target = linux
Target = linux-hardened
Target = linux-lts
Target = linux-zen


[Action]
Description = Save Linux kernel modules
When = PreTransaction
Depends = rsync
Exec = /bin/sh pacman-linux-update-modules-pre.sh $Target
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
man 5 alpm-hooks
```

And see the NeedsTargets specifier.

The manpage can be read online at https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/alpm-hooks.5